# Getting the outer CGRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cgrect

I have two `UIViews`, both of which obviously have `CGRects` each. One `UIView` fills the screen whereas the other just fills part of it in the middle. I have the `CGRect` of the smaller `UIView`, but how can I get the `CGRect` of the one outside of it - excluding the size of the smaller one so that the background can be dimmed, but not the content of the inner `UIView`?

This is what my `UIViewController` looks like so you can get a better idea of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I want to dim the *outer* `UIView`, not the inner one - but I don't have the CGRect of the outer one *excluding the inner `UIView`* so I've had to do it the other way around for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CGRect is a square size. If you want to know the outer aria you need to compute 4 CGRects. The top, left, right and bottom space.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks to me like the outer view is responsible for drawing your content and the inner view is your selection rectangle right?

If so, then I think you are going to want to draw your content twice when you have this selection mode active. You will:

1. draw one pass dimmed - adjust the colors yourself (you can either draw the whole area or clip away the inner area using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042725/drawrect-how-do-i-do-an-inverted-clip))
2. draw the second inner pass with a clip rect setup so only your content inside the rect for your selection rectangle is drawn

Or

1. draw all your content like normal
2. set your clipping mask (using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042725/drawrect-how-do-i-do-an-inverted-clip) so that just the outer area is rendered) and then draw a black rect with some degree of transparency over your whole scene