# Round Corners of resizable view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

Ive been using the code shown below to round selected corners of views, however am now having trouble achieving this on a resizable view as the layer? isn't updated each time the view is resized.

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}

titleLabelView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10)
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298335/how-to-round-off-one-corner-of-a-resizable-uiview-in-ios) but its quite old and all done in objC.

Is there a way of rounding selected corners in swift for resizable views?

----- EDIT -----

So essentially what i have is a text table that i have set to resize based on the size of the text.

In most cases i can just use:

```
myTextLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

However this does all 4 corners.  So if i want to round just the top 2 then i need to use the extension above.  Now because i am using scrollViewDidEndDecelerating to set the content for the label (i need to get the indexPath for the cell at the centre of the collectionView so i can set the text label)

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    GeneralFunctions.getIndexOfCell(sender: self) { (index) in
        self.titleLabel.text = self.partArray[index].title
        self.titleLabel.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10)
        self.descriptionLabel.text = self.partArray[index].description
        self.descriptionLabel.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 10)
        self.backgroundLabelView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        self.backgroundLabelView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.backgroundLabelView.layoutSubviews()
    }

}
```

Using viewDidLayoutSubViews doesn't work in this case as there is a lag between accelerating ending and the layout.  I have tried using the same code(without the check for the centre index) inside viewDidLayoutSubViews but the result is the same.

[image]

And The label does resize correctly when i don't use any of the corner rounding.

[image]

Comment: Without checking the linked question (and I expect answer), can you explain the exact issue? Conversion from Obj-C to Swift is pretty straightforward. What have you tried? You question is rather vague.

Comment: In particular, in the question you referenced, pay particular attention to doing the resize in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, I've solved it by using this function like

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    self.roundCorners(.allCorners, radius: 6, borderColor: nil, borderWidth: nil)
})
```

I am using this function a lot for `UITableViewCell`, and my whole code looks like

```
private var didLayoutSubview = false {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.roundCorners(.allCorners, radius: 6, borderColor: nil, borderWidth: nil)
        })
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    if !self.didLayoutSubview {
        self.didLayoutSubview = true
    }
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

So basically, calling this function in main thread helped, and I am calling it inside `layoutSubivews` because I think it is the place.

My function

```
func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor?, borderWidth: CGFloat?) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.frame = self.bounds
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask

    if borderWidth != nil {
        addBorder(mask, borderWidth: borderWidth!, borderColor: borderColor!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you subclassed uiView to achieve this or are you feeding it a uiView?