# Cut transparent hole in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgcontext

Looking to create a view that has a transparent frame inside of it so that the views behind the view can be seen through this transparent frame, but areas outside of this will not show through. So essentially a window within the view.

Hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
 CGRect hole = CGRectMake(100, 100, 250, 250);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

CGContextAddRect(context, hole);
CGContextClip(context);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```

but the clear does not override the black so whole background is black. Any ideas along these lines?

Comment: yes it is dead @Fattie

Answer (score 47):

This is my implementation (as I did needed a view with transparent parts):

**Header (.h) file:**

```
// Subclasses UIview to draw transparent rects inside the view

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PartialTransparentView : UIView {
    NSArray *rectsArray;
    UIColor *backgroundColor;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame backgroundColor:(UIColor*)color andTransparentRects:(NSArray*)rects;

@end
```

**Implementation (.m) file:**

```
#import "PartialTransparentView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation PartialTransparentView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame backgroundColor:(UIColor*)color andTransparentRects:(NSArray*)rects
{
    backgroundColor = color;
    rectsArray = rects;
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.opaque = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    [backgroundColor setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    // clear the background in the given rectangles
    for (NSValue *holeRectValue in rectsArray) {
        CGRect holeRect = [holeRectValue CGRectValue];
        CGRect holeRectIntersection = CGRectIntersection( holeRect, rect );
        [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(holeRectIntersection);
    }

}


@end
```

Now to add a view with partial transparency, you need to import the PartialTransparentView custom UIView subclass, then use it as follows:

```
NSArray *transparentRects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 20)],[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 150, 10, 20)], nil];
PartialTransparentView *transparentView = [[PartialTransparentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,400) backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.75] andTransparentRects:rects];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

This will create a view with 2 transparent rects.
Of course you can add as many rects as you wish, or just use one.
The above code is only handling rectangles, so if you wish to use circles, you will have to modify it.

Comment: For CIRCULAR transparent layer, modify draw rect as :

Comment: Hey @MosibAsad, could you let us know what to modify draw rect as? It didn't show up.. thanks!

Comment: Hey Daspianist, See my complete answer in the next comment. Sorry for the late reply!!

Comment: @Lefteris amazing job!

Comment: @Fry I had the same issue and solved it by setting the PartialTransparentView 's property "isOpaque" to "NO" (This can also be set on the .xib on the "Attribute Inspector" > "View" > "Drawing" > "Opaque")

Comment: How to make clickable means user interaction enable only that transparent layer @Lefteris

Comment: This also draws a black circle for me. I cant get it to be clear.

Comment: Same for me. It draws a black rect. `isOpaque` doesn't help. Did someone managed to solve it?

Comment: Somehow setting `backgroundColor` makes the gap black. Works without setting the `backgroundColor`

Answer (score 35):

Another solution:
The Big rect is all the view (yellow color) and the small is the transparent rect.
The color opacity is settable.

```swift
let pathBigRect = UIBezierPath(rect: bigRect)
let pathSmallRect = UIBezierPath(rect: smallRect)

pathBigRect.appendPath(pathSmallRect)
pathBigRect.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
fillLayer.path = pathBigRect.CGPath
fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
//fillLayer.opacity = 0.4
view.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Lefteris Answer is absolutely right, however, it creates transparent Rects. For CIRCULAR transparent layer, modify draw rect as

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [backgroundColor setFill];
     UIRectFill(rect);

    for (NSValue *holeRectValue in rectsArray) {
        CGRect holeRect = [holeRectValue CGRectValue];
        CGRect holeRectIntersection = CGRectIntersection( holeRect, rect );

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        if( CGRectIntersectsRect( holeRectIntersection, rect ) )
        {
            CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
            CGContextClip(context);
            CGContextClearRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor );
            CGContextFillRect( context, holeRectIntersection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mosib this does not draw more than one circles

Comment: @xs2bush you find any solution for draw multiple circle

Comment: @Jigar see my answer below

Answer (score 12):

I used `UIBezierPath` to handle cutting out the transparent hole.
The following code goes into a subclass of the `UIView` that you want to draw a transparent hole:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Clear any existing drawing on this view
    // Remove this if the hole never changes on redraws of the UIView
    CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);

    // Create a path around the entire view
    UIBezierPath *clipPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];

    // Your transparent window. This is for reference, but set this either as a property of the class or some other way
    CGRect transparentFrame;
    // Add the transparent window
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:transparentFrame cornerRadius:5.0f];
    [clipPath appendPath:path];

    // NOTE: If you want to add more holes, simply create another UIBezierPath and call [clipPath appendPath:anotherPath];

    // This sets the algorithm used to determine what gets filled and what doesn't
    clipPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
    // Add the clipping to the graphics context
    [clipPath addClip];

    // set your color
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // (optional) set transparency alpha
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.7f);
    // tell the color to be a fill color
    [tintColor setFill];
    // fill the path
    [clipPath fill];
}
```

Comment: This is really great answer, as UIBezierPath gives great flexibility!
Just one note: to make it work, mark view as non-opaque (either in IB or via code)

Answer (score 8):

@mosib's answer was a lot of help for me until I wanted to draw more than one circular cutouts in my view. After struggling a little bit, I updated my drawRect like this (code in swift...sorry bad editing):

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{     
    backgroundColor.setFill()   
    UIRectFill(rect)

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

    for aRect in self.rects
    {
        let holeEnclosingRect = aRect
        CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, nil, holeEnclosingRect) // use CGPathAddRect() for rectangular hole
        /*
        // Draws only one circular hole
        let holeRectIntersection = CGRectIntersection(holeRect, rect)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        if( CGRectIntersectsRect(holeRectIntersection, rect))
        {
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, holeRectIntersection)
        //CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke)
        CGContextClip(context)
        //CGContextClearRect(context, holeRectIntersection)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, holeRectIntersection)
        CGContextClearRect(context, holeRectIntersection)
        }*/
    }
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, self.bounds)
    layer.path = path
    layer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    self.layer.mask = layer

}
```

Comment: This works great... unless two holes overlap themselves. In that case, the intersection between them is not a hole. Do you know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

This will do the clipping:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor );
CGContextFillRect( context, rect );

CGRect holeRectIntersection = CGRectIntersection( CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50), rect );

if( CGRectIntersectsRect( holeRectIntersection, rect ) )
{
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextClearRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor );
    CGContextFillRect( context, holeRectIntersection);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Implementation of the @[Lefteris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312312/lefteris) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15810658/1442935) on Swift 4:

```
import UIKit

class PartialTransparentView: UIView {
    var rectsArray: [CGRect]?

    convenience init(rectsArray: [CGRect]) {
        self.init()

        self.rectsArray = rectsArray

        backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        isOpaque = false
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundColor?.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)

        guard let rectsArray = rectsArray else {
            return
        }

        for holeRect in rectsArray {
            let holeRectIntersection = rect.intersection(holeRect)
            UIColor.clear.setFill()
            UIRectFill(holeRectIntersection)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only one that works for me - but how does one make it a circle rather than a square? Thanks.

Comment: how to use this.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation supports Rectangles and Circles, written in swift:
[PartialTransparentMaskView](https://github.com/heigong/PartialTransparentMaskView)

```
class PartialTransparentMaskView: UIView{
    var transparentRects: Array<CGRect>?
    var transparentCircles: Array<CGRect>?
    weak var targetView: UIView?

    init(frame: CGRect, backgroundColor: UIColor?, transparentRects: Array<CGRect>?, transparentCircles: Array<CGRect>?, targetView: UIView?) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        if((backgroundColor) != nil){
            self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        }

        self.transparentRects = transparentRects
        self.transparentCircles = transparentCircles
        self.targetView = targetView
        self.opaque = false
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundColor?.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)

        // clear the background in the given rectangles
        if let rects = transparentRects {
            for aRect in rects {

                var holeRectIntersection = CGRectIntersection( aRect, rect )

                UIColor.clearColor().setFill();
                UIRectFill(holeRectIntersection);
            }
        }

        if let circles = transparentCircles {
            for aRect in circles {

                var holeRectIntersection = aRect

                let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

                if( CGRectIntersectsRect( holeRectIntersection, rect ) )
                {
                    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
                    CGContextClip(context);
                    CGContextClearRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
                    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor)
                    CGContextFillRect( context, holeRectIntersection);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my general swift implementation.

- For static views add tuples to the holeViews array as (theView, isRound)
- If you want to dynamically assign the views as I needed to, set the generator to something, say maybe `{someViewArray.map{($0,false)}} // array of views, not round`
- Use the view's corner radius instead of the isRound flag if you want, isRound is just easier for making circles.
- Note that isRound is really isEllipseThatWillBeRoundIfTheViewIsSquare
- Most code won't need the public's/internal's.

Hope it helps someone, thanks to the other contributors

```
public class HolyView : UIView {
    public var holeViews = [(UIView,Bool)]()
    public var holeViewsGenerator:(()->[(UIView,Bool)])?

    internal var _backgroundColor : UIColor?
    public override var backgroundColor : UIColor? {
        get {return _backgroundColor}
        set {_backgroundColor = newValue}
    }

    public override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        if (backgroundColor == nil) {return}

        let ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        backgroundColor?.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)

        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        UIRectClip(rect)

        let views = (holeViewsGenerator == nil ? holeViews : holeViewsGenerator!())
        for (view,isRound) in views {
            let r = convertRect(view.bounds, fromView: view)
            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, r)) {
                let radius = view.layer.cornerRadius
                if (isRound || radius > 0) {
                    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctxt, kCGBlendModeDestinationOut);
                    UIBezierPath(roundedRect: r,
                                byRoundingCorners: .AllCorners,
                                cornerRadii: (isRound ? CGSizeMake(r.size.width/2, r.size.height/2) : CGSizeMake(radius,radius))
                    ).fillWithBlendMode(kCGBlendModeDestinationOut, alpha: 1)
                }
                else {
                    UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(r, kCGBlendModeDestinationOut)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something quick and effective, I added a library ([TAOverlayView](https://github.com/TobogganApps/TAOverlayView)) to CocoaPods that allows you to create overlays with rectangular/circular holes, allowing the user to interact with views behind the overlay. I used it to create this tutorial for one of our apps:

[image: Tutorial using the TAOverlayView]

You can change the background by setting the `backgroundColor` of the overlay with something like `UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.85)`, depending on your color and opaqueness needs.

Comment: This is actually a pretty sweet solution which works great for me.

Comment: But it does not support iOS 7 :(

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by giving the view's layer a border.

```
class HollowSquareView: UIView {
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 10.0
  }
}
```

This will give you a square frame of width 10 and a transparent core.

You can also set the layer's `cornerRadius` to half the view's width and this will give you a hollow circle.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28892625/4912616) from Bushra Shahid and it worked good, but it has a problem if the circles overlap each other.

I used this different approach which works well in such case:

```swift
class HoleView: UIView {
    var holes: [CGRect] = [] {
        didSet {
            lastProcessedSize = .zero
            createMask()
        }
    }

    private var lastProcessedSize = CGSize.zero

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        createMask()
    }

    private func createMask() {
        guard lastProcessedSize != frame.size,
            holes.count > 0
            else { return }

        let size = frame.size

        // create image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            else { return }

        UIColor.white.setFill()
        context.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))

        UIColor.black.setFill()
        holes.forEach { context.fillEllipse(in: $0) }

        // apply filter to convert black to transparent
        guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(),
            let cgImage = image.cgImage,
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIMaskToAlpha")
            else { return }

        filter.setDefaults()
        filter.setValue(CIImage(cgImage: cgImage), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        guard let result = filter.outputImage,
            let cgMaskImage = CIContext().createCGImage(result, from: result.extent)
            else { return }

        // Create mask
        let mask = CALayer()
        mask.frame = bounds
        mask.contents = cgMaskImage
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

In summary:

- You create a `UIImage` mask in black and white instead of with/transparent.
- Use [`CIMaskToAlpha`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIMaskToAlpha) `CIFilter` to convert it to a transparent/white mask.
- Use the generated `CGImage` as content of a `CALayer`
- User tht `CALayer` as view mask.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'll have to answer as missed the comment and filled an answer form :)
I really'd like Carsten to provide more information about the best way to do what he propose.

You could use

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image
```

to create a background 'color' image of any complexity. An image could be either created programmatically if you are familiar with drawing classes or statically if the windows frames are predefined.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up "Faking" it

windowFrame is a property

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
CGRect rootFrame = [[Navigation rootController] view].frame;

CGSize deviceSize = CGSizeMake(rootFrame.size.width, rootFrame.size.height);

CGRect topRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, deviceSize.width, windowFrame.origin.y);
CGRect leftRect = CGRectMake(0, topRect.size.height, windowFrame.origin.x, windowFrame.size.height);
CGRect rightRect = CGRectMake(windowFrame.size.width+windowFrame.origin.x, topRect.size.height, deviceSize.width-windowFrame.size.width+windowFrame.origin.x, windowFrame.size.height);
CGRect bottomRect = CGRectMake(0, windowFrame.origin.y+windowFrame.size.height, deviceSize.width, deviceSize.height-windowFrame.origin.y+windowFrame.size.height);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, topRect);
CGContextFillRect(context, leftRect);
CGContextFillRect(context, rightRect);
CGContextFillRect(context, bottomRect);
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code create more than circle

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // Drawing code
    UIColor *bgcolor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:1.0f];//Grey

    [bgcolor setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    if(!self.initialLoad){//If the view has been loaded from next time we will try to clear area where required..

        // clear the background in the given rectangles
        for (NSValue *holeRectValue in _rectArray) {
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            CGRect holeRect = [holeRectValue CGRectValue];

            [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];

            CGRect holeRectIntersection = CGRectIntersection( holeRect, rect );

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor );
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);

            CGContextFillEllipseInRect( context, holeRectIntersection );

        }
    }

    self.initialLoad=NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Including an answer for Xamarin Studio iOS using C#. This draws a single rounded rectangle with 60% Alpha. Mostly taken from the answer from @mikeho

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    base.Draw(rect);

    //Allows us to draw a nice clear rounded rect cutout
    CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

    // Create a path around the entire view
    UIBezierPath clipPath = UIBezierPath.FromRect(rect);

    // Add the transparent window to a sample rectangle
    CGRect sampleRect = new CGRect(0f, 0f, rect.Width * 0.5f, rect.Height * 0.5f);
    UIBezierPath path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(sampleRect, sampleRect.Height * 0.25f);
    clipPath.AppendPath(path);

    // This sets the algorithm used to determine what gets filled and what doesn't
    clipPath.UsesEvenOddFillRule = true;

    context.SetFillColor(UIColor.Black.CGColor);
    context.SetAlpha(0.6f);

    clipPath.Fill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS UIView add a hole

Key point us `evenOdd`

```
let view = self.imageView!
let horizontalPerc = 0.8
let verticalPerc = 0.2

let bigFrame = view.frame
let bigFrameSize = bigFrame.size

let smallFrameSizeWidth = bigFrameSize.width * horizontalPerc
let smallFrameSizeHeight = bigFrameSize.height * verticalPerc

let smallFrameCenterX = view.center.x - smallFrameSizeWidth / 2
let smallFrameCenterY = view.center.y - smallFrameSizeHeight / 2

var smallRect = CGRect(
    origin: CGPoint(
        x: smallFrameCenterX,
        y: smallFrameCenterY
    ),
    size: CGSize(
        width: smallFrameSizeWidth,
        height: smallFrameSizeHeight
    )
)

let bigPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bigFrame)
let smallPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: smallRect, cornerRadius: 14)

bigPath.append(smallPath)
bigPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
fillLayer.path = bigPath.cgPath
fillLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
fillLayer.opacity = 0.7
self.view.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
```

Answer (score -3):

Do it the other way around! Place those views you would like to see through the "hole" in a separate view of the right size. Then set "clipsToBounds" to YES and put that view on top. The view with the "transparent" frame is the undermost then. "clipsToBounds" means everything outside of the box/hole is cut off.

Then you might have to deal how touches are handled. But that's another question. Maybe setting userInteractionEnabled on the according views is enough.

Comment: That's way too complicated to do right, the window might move with scrolling or any other animation and the view "behind" must not move, isn't it ? But your solution is a nice point of view, thanks for sharing.

Comment: It's not that complicated. You need to get the view hierarchy right :) What exactly should move how and what should be fix?

Comment: I dunno, that's not my question you know :) but any kind of animation is possible and i'l unlikely be wrong to say more than a half of views are scrollable at iOs world. That gives us the 'window' moving and I'd expect the 'prospect' not to move together.

Comment: If you don't want the "window"/"hole" being moved you have two options: a) Add the view to the super view of the view being moved. b) Listen to delegate callbacks of the view being moved and move the "window"/"hole" according into the other direction. In any case you are going to stay flexible - you just have to rearrange your view hierarchy.

Comment: a) adding the 'prospect' view to a 'window' superview will make 'prospect' invisible as the 'window' view has solid background b) i'm very confident there's just no effective tools to catch all animation events, please share if you are aware of some, i'm very eager to hear.