# Crop a part of viewcontroller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, viewcontroller

I want to crop a portion of the viewcontroller in semicircle so that the viewcontroller behind it would be visible throught the cropped portion. Is there a way to do it using objective-c or any custom control already available.

1. A TableviewContoller with 10 cells
2. An ImageWiderContoller with
       big image and other controls

First cell of the table should have a semicircle, through which the ImageWiderContoller (which is below TableviewContoller) should be visible
So Swiping left on tableview should reveil the imageWiderController

Comment: [My Answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711248/cut-transparent-hole-in-uiview/15810658#15810658) is probably what you are looking for

Comment: A viewController on which another viewController is pushed or presented cannot be seen under the previous one. To check just set the presented viewController's view's background to clear.

Comment: This is not true @ZeMoon, because if the ViewController is presented modally you can set the `UIModalPresentationStyle` to `OverCurrentContext` and the previous viewController view is visible

Comment: @Lefteris Oh, this has been introduced in iOS 8. That's great to hear!

Comment: You can use container view controller for that , instead cropping.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I think of doing it is having a  custom `UIView` and set that as default view of your top most `UIViewController`. Inside that `UIView's` `drawRect()` method you can draw whatever shapes you want (transparent included). Like if you want to draw a transparent circle in the middle of your controller, you would do this in `drawRect()` of your UIView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [[UIColor orangeColor] setFill]; //background Fill
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill]; //circle Fill.
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, (CGRect){self.center.x - 25.0f, self.center.y - 25.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f});
}
```

In initWithFrame: of the same UIView add this:

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

P.S: As mentioned by @Lefteris Obviously set your `UIViewController`'s `UIModalPresentationStyle` to OverCurrentContext so that it appears over the same controller.

Note: by transparent I meant the area of top controller which shows contents of the controller underneath, as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Sabir Ali . I have edited my question to explain my real need

Comment: You can use the same `drawRec:` appraoch by customising UITableViewCell class and putting this drawRect: function in there. Then you can use that customised `UITableViewCell` for first cell of your table and default cell for the rest. Considering your updated question It should work just fine. (PS: if I'm still getting you wrong, please share a mockup of desired Customisation and I'd be happy to help)

Comment: Exactly the same idea what I have implemented but I was looking for something other than this. But I would give one up for your answer though.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj, if you mean you are looking for a different approach for the same result, I'd be interested in knowing your find :)

Comment: Ya sure @Sabir Ali I'll update once when I get new idea for my task.