# Creating a transparent hole on UIVisualEffect view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uivisualeffectview

I'm trying to create a transparent hole kind of view on the UIVisualEffectView. I was following the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15810658/1084075). I have attached my sample code which I worked on [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qd8g960zcczkth8/BlurEffect.zip?dl=0). I'm trying to create a transparent view whose frame is taken from the image view behind the blurry view. Anyone could tell me what is that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14):

You can use a `UIBezierPath` to create the mask you want.

```
blurView.layer.mask = ({
    CGRect roundedRect = self.bounds;
    roundedRect.origin.x = roundedRect.size.width / 4.0f;
    roundedRect.origin.y = roundedRect.size.height / 4.0f;
    roundedRect.size.width /= 2.0f;
    roundedRect.size.height /= 2.0f;

    CGFloat cornerRadius = roundedRect.size.height / 2.0f;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
    UIBezierPath *croppedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedRect cornerRadius:cornerRadius];
    [path appendPath:croppedPath];
    [path setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

    CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    mask.path = path.CGPath;
    mask.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    mask;
});
```

Comment: How to set that rounded clear view only clickable means user interaction enable only on that portion @cnotethegr8

Comment: note that `[path setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];` is unnecessary as `mask.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;` takes the effect.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 version of the solution for lazy ones :)

```
    var roundedRect = visualEffectsView.bounds
    roundedRect.origin.x = roundedRect.size.width / 4
    roundedRect.origin.y = roundedRect.size.height / 4
    roundedRect.size.width = roundedRect.size.width / 2
    roundedRect.size.height = roundedRect.size.height / 2

    let cornerRadius = roundedRect.size.height / 2

    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: visualEffectsView.bounds)
    let croppedPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: roundedRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
    path.append(croppedPath)
    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    mask.fillRule = .evenOdd
    visualEffectsView.layer.mask = mask
```