# Custom uiview with window type feature to see background view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

Here yellow view is not simple single layer on a UIView, it holds more that two images in a stack manner. Here yellow view is the result which looks like a wall effect applied on real wall. Now on that effect view I have to clip some part of view selected by user.
[image: images shows a yellow view which has a window at centre of the view]
Please help for such a requirement, which shows in the image provided. The view has to be clipped with the user defined region, that part has be with clear colour so that background view can be visible.
This yellow view can hold any number of images.

Comment: There is a objective-c solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711248/cut-transparent-hole-in-uiview

Comment: `is not simple single layer on a UIView` I don't think it changes the idea of the linked answer. Adapt to your specific case, it should work. If you can't make it work, explain why in your question and if it's necessary the question will be reopened.