# Add blur effect on a Mapbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I want to add blur effect in mapbox.when first time load map that time only display current location in map other map is blue.see screenshot

[image]

when i move the userlocation to another location than other location is clear on the map.also display annotation in specific location
see screenshot

[image]

help me how can implement this

here i will some implement code

```
- (CGPoint)convertLatLongCoord:(CGPoint)latLong {
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size];
    CGFloat SCALE = MIN(screenSize.width, screenSize.height) / (2.0 * EARTH_RADIUS);
    CGFloat OFFSET = MIN(screenSize.width, screenSize.height) / 2.0;
    CGFloat x = EARTH_RADIUS * cos(latLong.x) * cos(latLong.y) * SCALE + OFFSET;
    CGFloat y = EARTH_RADIUS * cos(latLong.x) * sin(latLong.y) * SCALE + OFFSET;

    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"data=%f",self.mapview.userLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    CLLocation *currentLoc=[locations objectAtIndex:0];
    _coordinate=currentLoc.coordinate;
CGPoint latLong = {_coordinate.latitude, _coordinate.longitude};
    oldcord = [self convertLatLongCoord:latLong];
    NSLog(@"Cartesian Coordinate: (%f, %f)",oldcord.x, oldcord.y);

}
```

in this code i will get perfect view pixel point of UserLocation coordinate.after i want to clear blur in view using CGPoint but i can not get it.i think i will create array of CGPoint and than clear using line to blur of view but i can not got it pls suggest me.

i also use this lib but i can not get idea to much  https://github.com/DenHeadless/Shapes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as per Logic I have added in my comment [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247785/implement-fogblur-in-map) I have **made a sample** for you [**download it here**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78701794/SampleTester.zip), check the result below

[image]

The sample contains following logic.

1. Using iOS Map, added a Custom UIView above the Map the class for the
   UIView is `DrawView` which actually handles all the drawing and
   erasing part.
2. We are having `CLLocationManager` of course to determine user's movement.
3. As soon as `CLLocationManager` start giving locations, we convert the coordinates with respect of MapView pin location using following code

   ```
   CGPoint pt=[self.map convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:self.view];
   ```

   and we pass the `CGPoint` which is the converted value for the UIView to clear the area in drawing as

   ```
   [self.drawView eraseAtPoint:pt];
   ```
4. When CGPoint from user's coordinate is passed to the DrawView `eraseAtPoint` function we erase an area of defined radius, and it clears out the area as wanted.
5. I have added a sample `directions.gpx` file to simulate GPS location, the sample GIF shows the movement.

**Note:** Link for the project will expire after **14 March,2017**, so keep it downloaded, in any case if you want the sample again ping in comment. Feel free to do modifications as you need.

**Update:**

Adding capability to erase area in circles instead of squares, just replace the `drawRect` function in **DrawView** with the code below

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {    

    // Drawing code
    UIColor *backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:1.0f];//Grey

    [backgroundColor setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    if(!self.initialLoad){//If the view has been loaded from next time we will try to clear area where required..

        // clear the background in the given rectangles
        for (NSValue *holeRectValue in _rectArray) {
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            CGRect holeRect = [holeRectValue CGRectValue];

            [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];

            CGRect holeRectIntersection = CGRectIntersection( holeRect, rect );

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor );
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);

            CGContextFillEllipseInRect( context, holeRectIntersection );

        }
    }

    self.initialLoad=NO;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: in mapbox i will get wrong cgpoint (CGPoint) pt = (x = 1040634.6362283671, y = -389230.46748177585)

Comment: @Jigar I have no idea about `MapBox`, what you can do is keep iOS Map in the view hidden and get the calculation right, the gps position will still move on your MapBox map, just an idea. You can always dig into MapBox classes, tutorial and forum to find answer, the basic idea of your solution is there in the sample, this the way of doing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711248/cut-transparent-hole-in-uiview i will try this code for create circle .and i got it but only create one circle not multiple i need create multiple circle instead of rectangle if you have some idea than tell me

Comment: @Jigar Yes, check my update I have added code to erase area with circles.