# How to make the height of the cursor same with the height of text in UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I have UITextField with too long cursor(the cursor for "123123" in the following image)

[image]

How to make the height of the cursor same with the height of text?

Comment: Your problem may be same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207961/ios-uitextview-linespacing-make-cursor-height-not-same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can't change the cursor height , but we can do some trick , select your textfield and change your textfield border style as `UITextBorderStyleNone`

you get the out put as

[image]

there after increase the font size of your textfield whatever you want , then you get the output as

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The cursor's height seems to be same with the height of the textField. So I set a constraint on the textfield's height and increase the font size.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i have some problem in another question if you are free so please help me

Comment: @john - sure, .

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424811/add-blur-effect-on-a-mapbox

Answer (score 17):

I accidentally stumbled across this question and even though it is a little old I feel compelled to answer it since the accepted answer actually isn't correct.

You can indeed change the height (or width) of the cursor. Just subclass the `UITextField` and override this method:

```
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position {
    CGRect rect = [super caretRectForPosition:position];
    rect.size.height = 42;
    return rect;
}
```

Comment: hi, i tried your answer and it worked so +1 for you, but when i changed the keyboard (from English(indian) to Japanes(kana) ) , the caret moves up when i enter a single character. **Xcode 10.1 & Swift**

Comment: Thank you, it is a great answer! It should be selected as correct. It is far more flexible and reliable solution. in my case, I also needed to change cursor's position according to different conditions. I could achieve it through this method

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your UITextField name is uiTextField. To set font size add the code below

```
_uITextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

in 2021 we have properties

```
TextFormField(
cursorHeight: 13,
cursorColor: Colors.black)
```

Comment: this is not UIKit / iOS