# How to change the size of blinking bar/line for specific UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, caret

i'm working on a project`(Swift4,Xcode 9.2)` which has a feature to get text input and the blinking bar/line should be of big size *`(it should be Square instead of bar/line)`*, so i placed a `UITextField` for Text but i don't understand how to change the size of that blinking line/bar.

So, is it possible to change the size of line/bar? and if Yes then how to do it?
i know how to change the color of that line/bar but this is something different.

Comment: If you do this, your app may get rejected during the review. Look at this SO question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747664/uitextfield-custom-cursor-image

Comment: You may be right, but i've done this Color Changing thing earlier and my app is still living on AppStore.

Comment: Related: [How to make the height of the cursor same with the height of text in UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546820/how-to-make-the-height-of-the-cursor-same-with-the-height-of-text-in-uitextfield) and [UITextView lineSpacing make cursor height not same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207961/ios-uitextview-linespacing-make-cursor-height-not-same)

Answer (score 7):

You can change the size by `overriding` the `frame` method for `cursor` as follows,

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.caretRect(for: position)
        let size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 50)
        // Calculating center y
        let y = rect.origin.y - (size.height - rect.size.height)/2
        rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x, y: y), size: size)
        return rect
    }
}
```

Set `CustomTextField` class in `xib/storyboard` identity inspector for that `textField`.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me on this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665841/weird-behaviour-of-caret-cursor-in-uitextfield**

Answer (score 1):

We can't change the cursor height, but we can do some trick, select your textfield and change your textfield border style as `UITextBorderStyleNone`

[Check the below link which is already given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546820/how-to-make-the-height-of-the-cursor-same-with-the-height-of-text-in-uitextfield)

there after increase the font size of your textfield whatever you want, then you get the output as

Comment: Hi, can you please help me on this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665841/weird-behaviour-of-caret-cursor-in-uitextfield**

Answer (score 1):

There are some unnecessary lines of codes, so this is the revised:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.caretRect(for: position)
        rect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x, y: .zero, width: 15, height: 30)
        return rect
    }
}
```