# Weird behaviour of caret/cursor in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

*(Xcode10.1 ,Swift, iOS 11&12)*
***Question: How to increase height of caret/cursor in UITextField***

***What I've tried so far:***
I've done this, and it works:

```
class BPTextField: UITextField {
    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.caretRect(for: position)
        let h = self.frame.height - 5
        let y_ = (self.frame.height - h)/2
        rect.origin.y = y_
        rect.size.height = h;
        return rect;
    }
}
```

But when I change the keyboard language (from English-India to Japanese-Kana) and type a single character, the caret/cursor moves to up side in the text field.

I've gone through these links:
[How to make the height of the cursor same with the height of text in UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546820/how-to-make-the-height-of-the-cursor-same-with-the-height-of-text-in-uitextfield)
[UITextView lineSpacing causes different cursor height inbetween paragraph lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207961/uitextview-linespacing-make-cursor-height-not-same)

**EDIT**
I'm using `YYText` library. I'm inserting this `BPTextField` into `YYLabel` as a `NSAttributedStringAttachment`:

```
let main = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text_)
main.yy_color = .darkGray
main.yy_font = questionFont
main.yy_lineSpacing = 5.0
main.yy_lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

//Attachment

let attachment = NSMutableAttributedString.yy_attachmentString(withContent: self.tf, contentMode: UIView.ContentMode.center, attachmentSize: self.tf.frame.size, alignTo: questionFont, alignment: YYTextVerticalAlignment.bottom)
attachment.yy_baselineOffset = -5.0
root.append(attachment)

//BPTextField

self.tf = BPTextField(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 13), size: CGSize(width: tfWidth.width + 7.5, height: tfWidth.height + 13.0)))
self.tf.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
self.tf.tag = 0
self.tf.font = questionFont
self.tf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
self.tf.textColor = .darkGray
self.tf.setRoundedCorners(corners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, withRadius: 4.0)
//self.tf.setLeftPaddingPoints(5.0)
//self.tf.setRightPaddingPoints(0.0)
self.tf.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9058823529, green: 0.9529411765, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
self.tf.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078431, green: 0.6156862745, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
self.tf.returnKeyType = .done
self.tf.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate `origin y` as below,

```
override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
    var rect = super.caretRect(for: position)
    let size = CGSize(width: rect.size.width, height: self.frame.height - 5)
    // Calculating center y
    let y = rect.origin.y - (size.height - rect.size.height)/2
    rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x, y: y), size: size)
    return rect
}
```

Comment: I will try and let you know., Thanks for instant support.

Comment: Yes, i tried but no luck... but +1 for your effort.

Comment: i've edited my question for you. thanks for your response.