# Removing specific area from blurred space MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any chance to remove blur on a specified area to achieve something like below? Assume that I have blurred MKMapView and want to remove circle shaped blurred area from MKMapView. Any other opinions to achieve something like this would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: for those with sufficient privileges: this is a repost of closed and deleted question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723394/removing-blur-effect-from-a-part-of-a-blurred-view-in-ios

Comment: I have deleted that post :)

Comment: *"Assume that I have blurred MKMapView"*. No, we should not make any assumption. Instead you should give us all the information you have. including code and attempts.

Comment: I do not have the code, and also don't know what to do, that's why I'm asking for. I could make the view blur but not able to remove the blurry from specified area.

Comment: @kkocabiyik I'd suggest you first achieve the blurring of the view (and there are tons of existing answers on that topic already here on Stack Overflow), so there's no need for us to repeat this here. Once you've learned how to make a snapshot, how to blur it, etc., you can then search for answers about masking images (i.e. cut out the circular center). Much like your original question, this is just too broad and doesn't demonstrate having done much research. The community will be much more receptive to narrower questions that demonstrate that you've done some homework.

Comment: for example for an answer it would be important to know how you blur.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670985/adding-a-circle-mask-layer-on-an-uiimageview